# jQuery SelectMenu closes after click

Tags: jquery-ui

I just updated to jQuery 1.4.2 & jQueryUI 1.8.2 w/the google cdn and now my jQuery selectmenu closes abruptly right after you click it.

I have a basic select and am instantiating it like so:

```
$('#myselectid').selectmenu({ maxHeight: 300 });
```

I should also point out that if I change the jQuery version to 1.3.2 and the jQueryUI version to 1.7.2 then it works...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
    this.newelement
        .bind('mousedown', function(event){
            self._toggle(event);
            //make sure a click won't open/close instantly
            if(o.style == "popup"){
                self._safemouseup = false;
                setTimeout(function(){self._safemouseup = true;}, 300);
            }
            return false;
        })
        .bind('click',function(){
            return false;
        })
```

To:

```
    this.newelement
        .bind('click', function(event){
            self._toggle(event);
            //make sure a click won't open/close instantly
            if(o.style == "popup"){
                self._safemouseup = false;
                setTimeout(function(){self._safemouseup = true;}, 300);
            }
            return false;
        })
```